# Increasing the width of messages listing in mail prompt

Tags: aix, mailx, mail-command

How to increase the width of listings in `mail` command prompt? Especially the message listing with the command `h`.

The current listing is truncated at 80 characters as showing below:

```bsh
$ mail
Mail [5.2 UCB] [AIX 5.X]  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/root": 467 messages 1 new 467 unread
 U463 daemon            Mon Mar 29 10:21  35/1291 "Output from cron job nice -n"
 U464 daemon            Mon Mar 29 10:26  32/1063 "Output from cron job nice -n"
 U465 daemon            Mon Mar 29 10:31  32/1065 "Output from cron job nice -n"
 U466 daemon            Mon Mar 29 10:51  32/1065 "Output from cron job nice -n"
>N467 daemon            Mon Mar 29 11:21  32/1131 "Output from cron job nice -n"
?
```

It respects the pts total lines but not the columns:

```bsh
$ echo "$COLUMNS x $LINES" 
120 x 35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible.

After examining the strings of `/usr/bin/mail` I choose two of them as how the message summaries are presented:

```
%c%c%3d To %-13.13s  %16.16s %8s
%c%c%3d To %-13.13s  %16.16s %8s "%s"
```

Further, I found an approximate of this 'mail' program.

`UCB Mail Version 5.2 (6/21/85)`

(I'll look for an alternative OSS program and see if I can port that to AIX.)

Comment: As an experiment - I found and packaged alpine-2.24 for AIX. See http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/alpine. I am curious for your feedback.